# UITableView not refreshing after dismissing ViewController above

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `ViewController` being presented using Apple's new default `ModalTransitionStyle`. And when that `ViewController` is dismissed, the `ViewController` below (that has a `TableView`) doesn't update the table.

I have tried `ViewWill/DidAppear` but in both cases, I get the error **`"Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional Value"`** when trying to access the table.

I have checked what methods get called and I found that `numberOfRowsInSection` gets called and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` doesn't get called. The table is for sure visible. It is not height 0 and `numberOfRowsInSection` doesn't get 0 returned.

I made a quick test project to demonstrate what I mean.

[Image when App Runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdjTk.png)

[When Popup button clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0P4R.png)

[When i go back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmo1c.png)

```
import UIKit

var cells = 5

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cells
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "test")

        return cell!
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.reloadData()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func popup(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "popover", sender: self)
    }


}

import UIKit

class PopoverViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        cells += 1
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func back(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "vc") as! ViewController
        self.dismiss(animated: true)


    }

}
```

What should happen is that everytime i go back to the view 1 more cell is being displayed. I checked if the count "Cell" is being increased and it is. I just cant figure out how to reload the table.

Comment: Check if the IBOutlets are connected properly. And do add some code so we can identify the issue.

Comment: I edited the Question so i hope its more clear now. The IBOutlets shouldnt be the problem as everything works except reloading the table after dismissing the popover

Comment: for going back no need to, `let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "vc") as! ViewController`if you describe to going back. Just use `dismiss`

Comment: I know that was just from testing from before. I used it to try and run viewDidLoad from there but that didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old answer:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
  self?.table.reloadData()
}
```

New Answer:

One of the your mistakes is that

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "vc") as! ViewController

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            vc.table.reloadData()
        })
```

The `vc` is not your living Main Controller, you've to send living controller's reference.

By the way.

```
class PopoverViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        cells += 1
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func back(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "vc") as! ViewController

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            vc.table.reloadData()
        })


    }

}
```

And your `viewDidLoad` method should be like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //table.reloadData()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        view.addSubview(table)
        table.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        table.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        table.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        table.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(notify),
                                               name: .notifier,
                                               object: nil)


        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.action,
                                                                 target: self,
                                                                 action: #selector(hh))
    }
```

`hh` function is just for `programmatically` present `Popover`

```
@objc private func notify(notification: NSNotification){
        //do stuff using the userInfo property of the notification object
        print("notification has called")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.table.reloadData()
        }
    }


extension Notification.Name {
    static let notifier = Notification.Name("notifier")
}
```

And change your `cells` variable like this:

```
var cells = 5{
    didSet{

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .notifier, object: nil)

    }
}
```

I've created a `Notification` pattern to messaging between pages. It worked for me. When you increase `cells` instance `Notification` has notified and cell's has updated.

Comment: That also gives me the error "found nil when unwrapping...".

Comment: are you checked your table view connection in storyboard?

Comment: Yes. They are all completely fine. I just redid all of them.

Comment: did you assign your cell identifier as "test" its so weird because I think after you dismiss the identifier "test" makes crash for program

Comment: The "test" isnt the problem. I just put it because i made this test project to demonstrate my problem.

Comment: if it's not special, can I look at your project to run & check?

Comment: The Problem is i cant share my Main Project online as it is a task for my School and if i share it I might run into problems. However if u want the dummy version i can share it with you if you tell me how.

Comment: so, just send the crashed page with running xcodeproj with a online file provider, I'll send it with solve.

Comment: storyboard and launch screen is missing :/

Comment: At least, I've created programmatically and solved your problem.

Comment: I dont know why the Storyboard wasnt in there. Regardless your solution is working perfectly fine thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As i understand `ViewController` is parent, `PopoverViewController` is child. After child is dismissed, parent should update tableview.

`viewDidLoad` is called once for parent, it wont be called for dismissal of child.

So, you may define any delegate or closure for child view controller, which reload tableview at parent. you can call it at completion of dismiss.
`dismiss(animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?)`

```
class PopoverViewController: UIViewController {

var onDismiss: (() -> Void)?
//...
}

// Also add this method to viewcontroller
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier = "popover" {
            guard let popoverVC = segue.destination as? PopoverViewController else {
                return
            }
            popoverVC.onDismiss = { [unowned self] in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

Also you don't need to create parent for dismissal. 
`let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main"..` this line is unnecessary. this new vc is not shown so if you try to reach it, crash will occur due to outlets' nil value.

Comment: I have tried this with calling vc.viewDidLoad() in that closure, same with vc.table.reloadData() and also vc.viewDid/WillAppear all of them dont reload the table. They either crash or give me the error "found nil while..."

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding. firstly do not call viewDidLoad() ever your self. i will edit my answer.

Comment: Your answer is working for the test project. However its not working as soon as the ViewController in embeded In a Navigation Controller. Ive got it working though now so thank you!